# Silex last insert id

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, silex

I could not found a short way to get latest insert id in silex

```
 $app['db']->insert('users', array(
                        'password' => password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
                        'email' => $data['email'],
                        'name' => $data['name'],
                        'surname' => $data['surname'],
                        'activation_code' => $activation_code,

                    )
                );
```

does anyone help me how to get latest insert ID

Answer (score 1):

Yes I found the solution,
since I am using PGSql I must have declare sequence.

```
$userId = $app['db']->lastInsertId('users_seq');
```

this code worked perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

If `$app["db"]` is a Doctrine DBAL connection, then it has a `lastInsertId()` method you can use.

Comment: $userId = $app['db']->lastInsertId(); this did not worked

Comment: by the way I am using PGSQL